# How do I initialize an alert within a function using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to add an alert when `gameOver()` is called. "Result of 'Alert' initializer is unused". How do I initialize the alert I created?

```
func gameOver() {
    round = 0
    score = 0
    self.changeTarget()
}
```

Solution Attempt:

```
func gameOver() {
    round = 0
    score = 0
    self.changeTarget()
    Alert(title: Text("Game Over"),
    message: Text("Thanks for playing"),
    dismissButton: Alert.Button.default( Text("Play Again")))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI framework you have several options for implementing `Alert`, for example:

`func alert<Item>(item: Binding<Item?>, content: (Item) -> Alert) -> some View where Item : Identifiable`

`func alert<Item>(item: Binding<Item?>, content: (Item) -> Alert) -> some View where Item : Identifiable`

Here is a simple example of using the first option:

```swift
struct GameOverAlert: View {

    @State private var round = 0
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var restartGame = false // variable for showing alert

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Text("round: \(round)")
            Text("score: \(score)")

            HStack { // used this style just for brevity
                Button(action: { self.score += 1 }) { Text("add score") }
                Button(action: { self.gameOver() }) { Text("over game") }
            }
            Spacer() // only for presenting result

        }
        .alert(isPresented: $restartGame) {
            Alert(title: Text("Your score is \(score)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Play again")) {
                self.playAgain()
            })
        }


    }

    // described logic here, but it should be in some ViewModel, etc
    private func gameOver() {
        restartGame = true
    }

    private func playAgain() {
        score = 0
        round = 0
    }

}
```

with code above you'll achieve this:

[image]

Comment: Okay so I'm trying to have a button appear when the score gets to 10. Where do I put my if statement within the Button{action}?

Comment: @Troy I don't understand the question above. The idea is that you change ```isPresented``` (for alert) bool variable somewhere and at this moment alert will show. For example you can add ```if self.score >= 10 { self.gameOver() }``` into button, which increases score and the alert will show when you'll reach 10

Comment: I figured it out! I'm still pretty new to swift and swiftUI. I was trying to apply python syntax. I'll post my solution.

Comment: @АлександрГрабовский - both lines you highlight in gray are the same (?)

Comment: @Duck wow, didn't noticed it, thanks. Will try to recall the answer and correct it

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working to display a game over alert.

```
.alert(isPresented: $alertIsVisible) { () -> Alert in
    let roundedValue = sliderValueRounded()
    if self.round == 5 {
        return Alert(title: Text("Game Over"), message: Text("Your score was \(score)."), dismissButton: .default(Text("Play Again")) {
        self.startOver()
        })
    } else {
    return Alert(title: Text(alertTitle()), message: Text("The slider's value is \(roundedValue). \n" + "You scored \(pointsForCurrentRound()) points!"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Play Again")){
        self.changeTarget()
        self.round += 1
        })}
}
```